# Disqus in Cordova/Ionic app gets stuck on Disqus page

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, disqus

I am trying to add Disqus to my Ionic/Cordova app. I have successfully got the Disqus widget to appear in a template using an iframe but if I click on the Disqus widget to login to Disqus to add a comment, or look at the Disqus community tab, for example, then the app goes to a non scrollable Disqus page that fills all of the screen and there is no way to get back to the app.

Is there a way to make the page it goes to scrollable and smaller than the screen so the user can get back into the app.

The Disqus code server on a static server is:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var params;
 var disqus_url;
 var disqus_title;
 var disqus_shortname;
 var disqus_identifier;
 
 window.onload = function () {
  var match,
   pattern = /\+/g,
   search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
   decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pattern, " ")); },
   query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  params = {};
  while (match = search.exec(query))
     params[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
     
  if (params["shortname"] === undefined || params["url"] === undefined || params["title"] === undefined) {
   alert("Required arguments missing");
  }
  else {
   loadComments(params["shortname"], params["url"], params["title"], params["identifier"]);
  }
 };
 
 function loadComments(shortname, url, title, identifier) {
  disqus_url = url;
  disqus_title = title;
  disqus_shortname = shortname;
  
  if (identifier !== undefined)
   disqus_identifier = identifier;
  else
   disqus_identifier = "";
 
  (function() {
   var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = false;
   dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
   (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();
 }
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
<a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">blog comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
</body>
</html>
```

In my app's controller I have:

```js
  var disqus_title = "TEST";
  var disqus_identifier = '/movie/' + 0;
  var disqus_url = 'http://example.com/movie/' + 0;
  var url = "http://example.com/disqus.html?";
  $scope.disqusurl = url + "shortname=example&url=" + encodeURIComponent(disqus_url) +
    "&title=" + encodeURIComponent(disqus_title) + "&identifier=" + encodeURIComponent(disqus_identifier);
  $scope.disqusurl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.disqusurl);
```

The relevant part of the template file looks like this:

```html
<ion-content>
  ...
  <iframe style="max-height: 40%;" src="{{disqusurl}}"></iframe>
  ...
</ion-content>
```

**EDIT**
The problem seems to be that the web links in the Disqus widget are launched within the app. If somehow the links could be made to open in an external browser then all might work fine but I can't see how to make pulled in HTML code work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try:

1) try to over ride disqus's css using !important selector

2) try to load in content with ajax

3) search and read articles like this: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472096-using-disqus-in-mobile-apps

4) have an iframe to a page on your website that has disqus, and make the iframe smaller than page height.

Comment: Thanks Globlee. (1) What CSS are you referring to?, (2) I am using the method recommended by Disqus I am not aware of an Ajax method can you elaborate?, (3) I have read that article and it mentions the problems I am having but does not give solutions, (4) I have tried restricting the iframe height (see my sample code), but this does not seem to work.

Comment: These were just general suggestions I have not looked deeply into this. In this case I would try 4. Have a page on your website where the disqus iframe is embedded and then use an iframe to that page, ie iframe inside an iframe. Hence the disqus will be full-page inside the iframe. Its a little confusing but I think it could work.

Comment: I am using an iframe in a page but when you click on one of the Disqus links (e.g. login) it takes you to another page which is full page and that is where the problem lie as there is no way to get back.

Comment: @BillNoble The same happens to me. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No sorry not found a solution yet